# Where can I find a comprehensive list of priming connections?

Tags: semantics, reference-request, neurolinguistics

Is there a website or a study I could find a detailed list or net of priming connections between words? Here's how I imagine it:

[image: Priming words]

Comment: What do you mean by "priming connections"?

Comment: If you are looking for semantic networks, there are many of them - take a look at [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/), for example.

Comment: Or [Framenet](https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu/fndrupal/).